# Where is the JetBrains IntelliJ openapi documentation?

Tags: documentation, intellij-idea

I have searched Google and JetBrains website, but I cannot find docs for the com.intellij packages.

Any IDEAs (:-))?

Comment: Still none javadoc ☹

Comment: In 2015, the documentation is here: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html

Comment: How is this a recommendation for a book or tool? It is asking where to find the official documentation of a specific thing. I don't get stackoverflow sometimes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from @Sorin, the official documentation is available here:
http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html

Here are some docs:

Lots of links here:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment

The SDK:
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development

Also, from the above link, you can check out the source code to the community edition, which should effectively act as API docs:

http://www.jetbrains.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983225

Comment: Pretty disappointing for a commercial product.

Comment: In 2015, the documentation exists, and is found here: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html

Answer (score 8):

It does not exist, either in javadoc or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There don't appear to be any, but at one time perhaps there was. There is a list of classes [here](http://apidoc.org/docset/16) which links to 404'd pages on jetbrains.com. This list itself is still kind of useful though.

Also the IntelliJ source is in [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/11.0/com/intellij/openapi/wm/ToolWindow.java) which is a very useful site!

Ctrl-clicking/auto-completing stuff to see the API in IDEA itself is also quite helpful. Unlike Eclipse, it doesn't give you a useless HTML page showing unreadable decompiled code.

Answer (score 0):

There is github repo of community edition: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community
Hope this helps