# IntelliJ plugin : How to import settings

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, intellij-plugin

In IntelliJ 12 (possibly earlier versions too) it is possible to import a jar with settings, previously exported.

I would like two write a plugin to specify a location where this settings jar can automatically be imported from. That would allow you to put a jar in your repository and in that way share it with your team.

With the [lack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584883/where-is-the-jetbrains-intellij-openapi-documentation) of online javadocs for the open-api, I've had a hard time working out how to do this.

What class in the plugin framework will allow me to import settings?

Comment: Haha, the `open` part of the `openapi` is a paradox :) Just use ctrl-alt-shift-N and try to figure it out... anyway I think your idea is a good one, good luck.

Comment: Idea has a lot of project-level properties, including code style, compiler configs and so on. They will be automatically copyed to .idea directory and can be pushed to repository. Imported settings most of all contains user-specific settings, like keymaps, templates and so on. Do you really need 'em to be shared across different users via plugin?

Comment: @vikingsteve Here's the first version: https://github.com/nieldw/ImportIdeaSettings

Comment: hehe, `System.out.println("HELLO SETTINGS!");`

Comment: @vikingsteve Every project starts with some "Hello World!", doesn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `ImportSettingsAction` is the class that provides the import action in the File menu. I bastardized it for my own purposes.