# Intellij idea gdsl. Add constructor to the class. Documentation for GDSL

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, dsl

I have an annotation which adds some methods and default constructor to annotated class.
I have managed to create a gdsl, to enable autocompletion in idea for methods, but I'm stuck with constructor and documentation is very poor.

Does anyone have any ideas, how to do this?

Maybe I could find a solution, in existing gdsl, but I can't remember any Transformation, related to constructors. Maybe you can remind me of any of them.

```
def objectContext = context(ctype: "java.lang.Object")

contributor(objectContext) {
  if (hasAnnotation("com.xseagullx.SomeAnnotation")) {
    // Here I want to add constructor's declaration(with empty arg's)
    // …
    // And then my methods.
    method name: 'someMethod', type: 'void', params: [:]
  }
}
```

**EDITED:** OK, if it's as @jasp say, and there is no DSL construct for declaring Constructors, I'm still asking for a good documentation sources, other than JB's confluence page. Tutorials and other sources. I'm familiar with **embedded** dsl's for groovy, grails and gradle.

Need smth. more structured, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit old, but I found myself looking for something similar.

The DSL you are looking for is
`method params: [:], constructor: true` although I don't understand why you'd need it; if a class doesn't declare any constructors doesn't IDEA always suggest the default one?

Comment: Yes, if the class _doesn't declare any constructors_… But not in my case, as class can have constructors, and default one is added by annotation. Anyway, thanks for the answer! It's good, that this thing is possible.

Comment: Ah, I see - fair enough. As for documentation, the answer seems to be that there isn't any (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584883/where-is-the-jetbrains-intellij-openapi-documentation) but I've found that the OpenAPI library itself (http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intellij/openapi/7.0.3) is usually good enough (if you have this as a dependency in your project, you'll also get pretty decent code completion in your GDSL files).

Answer (score 3):

All function invocations inside of GroovyDSL are just calls to wrappers around internal IDEA's Program Structure Interface (PCI). However it doesn't cover all of PCI's abilities, including default constructors functionality I believe. One of an evidence for that is [singletonTransform.gdsl](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness#ScriptingIDEforDSLawareness-Describingcustomannotations), which is bundled into IDEA from 9 version and describes @Singleton AST transformation. Here is it's code:

```
contributor(context()) {
  if (classType?.hasAnnotation("groovy.lang.Singleton")) {
    property name: "instance",
             type: classType?.getQualifiedName() ?: "java.lang.Object",
             isStatic: true
  }
}
```

As you can see it doesn't change a constructor and it's visibility, so IDEA will autocomplete this invalid code:

```
@Singleton class Foo {}
def foo = new Foo()
```

Futhermore [GDSL that describes the semantics of GroovyDSL](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness#ScriptingIDEforDSLawareness-DescribingGroovyDSLinternallanguageinitsownterms) (which is actually the part of /plugins/groovy/resources/standardDsls/metaDsl.gdsl of IDEA sources) doesn't provide any ability for describing of constructors.

In this case I suggest you use newify transformation which allows you to describe targetClass.name method returning created instance.

Comment: Thank you! I have expected smth more, but negative answer is still an answer.